# Migration silent error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I don't get a response.

Doing a trace, I get the following but I am not sure how to interpret it:

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

I am running rails 3.0.10.

Comment: It looks like all your migrations have run. What are you expecting to see output?

Comment: I also don't get any output when I rollback.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are the migrations being run, there's just not output from Rake? 2) Have you written proper "down" methods for `rake db:rollback`?

Comment: 1) Migrations are not being run 2) yes there are down methods for all of my migrations

Comment: Have you run rake db:create? Check out the table exist? if not exist then paste your database.yml file

Answer (score 0):

As coreyword suggested, perhaps there are no new migrations to run.
The `rake db:migrate` command will exit silently when there's nothing (new) to do.